# Why Unix domain takes so many buffer for small package

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, unix-socket

I have doing some unix domain and tcp/ip client/server test and find out 
the unix domain takes much more buffer than it really supposed to be,
both of them are using SOCK_STREAM .

In 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 linux ,  the unix domain client connect to unix domain server and the unix domain server send 44 bytes packages to client every 10 seconds ,  client  never call recv  so that all packages sent from server will
be all jammed in buffer , the following is what I observed :

```
ss -ax |grep "test"

Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                    Local Address:Port                                                     Peer Address:Port

u_str  ESTAB      0      768    /tmp/testud 22461998              * 22461997  
u_str  ESTAB      0      1536   /tmp/testud 22461998              * 22461997 
u_str  ESTAB      0      2304   /tmp/testud 22461998              * 22461997
```

I am doing the same test in tcp/ip  , as the following showes :

```
ss -at | grep "192.168"

State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port                 Peer Address:Port  
ESTAB      44     0      192.168.2.1:odnsp                192.168.2.2:distinct 
ESTAB      88     0      192.168.2.1:odnsp                192.168.2.2:distinct
ESTAB      132    0      192.168.2.1:odnsp                192.168.2.2:distinct
```

As you see , the unix domain Send-Q  has 768 bytes , but the actual packages only cost 44 bytes ,  and the tcp/ip Recv-Q takes  44 bytes for each package exactly .

My question is why send 44 bytes packages through SOCK_STREAM , the unix domain buffer cost 768 bytes each but tcp/ip buffer cost only 44 bytes ?!

Comment: BTW, you are comparing send-q and recv-q in comparing domain wiht internet sockets. Why is send-q piling up? You said, you aren't doing `recv`. That does not result in ACK going out. So why is send-q filling up? Maybe the high value is because of re-transmission counts. ?

Comment: in both unix domain and tcp/ip test , client do not call recv on purpose,  and both case server send 44 bytes and wait 10 seconds to send another 44 bytes, then ss -ax will see Send-Q has 768,1536,...  in testing unix domain   ,  and ss -at  will see 44,88,... in Recv-Q in testing tcp/ip  , I have no idea why this happened .